# What does this weird function definition mean?

Tags: c, function

I came across this C program in [a blog post](https://karwin.blogspot.in/2012/11/c-pointers-explained-really.html):

```
main()
{
    int n;
    n = 151;
    f(n);
}

f(x)
int x;
{
    printf("%d.\n", x);
}
```

The post doesn't explain it. Can anybody explain what this weird function definition means?

Comment: Please don't change the code/question once you ask. This might be misleading to people who have a look at the answer and find it unrelated.

Comment: @ruakh, You have changed my entire code. There was an another code before the code you've have included in my question. So I've to edit this one more.

Comment: What part of this code don't you understand? Please be specific what you need explained.

Comment: @vishram0709, Scotia: Mea culpa.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is the K&R style of C code, it's still valid C syntax, but I suggest you not using it in new-written code.

```
f(x)
int x;
```

is equivalent to ANSI C:

```
void f(int x)
```

---

[K&R C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%26R_C#K.26R_C) is the C language described in the first edition of the book [*C programming language*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language) by Brian Kernighan and Dennis Ritchie, and named after the two authors. The second edition of the book updated to use ANSI C.

Comment: It's still _valid,_ even in C11 so, while you are correct in _suggesting_ it shouldn't be used, saying "don't use it" could be considered a little too strong. Especially since glibc uses it :-)

Answer (score 6):

```
f(x)
int x;
{
    printf("%d.\n", x);
}
```

is an older way of defining function. Now it can be read as

```
void f(int x)
{
    printf("%d.\n", x);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This code is simply bad.

1. Obsolete declaration of function `f()`
2. There should be forward declaration of `f()` before `main()`
3. Return type is missing for `f()`

Comment: Also, the compiler may make `f()` default to int as return type, which in turn will lead to the compiler complaining for non returned value.

Answer (score 0):

please change your c learning source!

that is a very old style of C (K&R C).

```
f(x)

int x;
{}
```

is equivalent to

```
void f(int x)
{}
```

you should really not wasting time learning that.

look for sources that teach ANSI C C89/C90 and also note the new features of C99 (that isn't widely adopted by many compilers, so know the differences)

Comment: @RobertMutke have you ever worked on some serios industrial products? the most compiler for the embedded systems that are certified does not actually support c99.

Comment: Let me disagree with you. gcc, keil, iar fully support c99

Comment: @RobertMutke gcc does not fully support c99! and you seldem will use gcc in safety relevant products. also i haven't sad that c99 should be ignored. i just sad 'know the basics' and know the differences.

Comment: @RobertMutke also look at this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/139479/how-universally-is-c99-supported and this link http://gcc.gnu.org/c99status.html

Answer (score -2):

This is a very old style of coding. This doesn't work out in ANSI.
Better use something like

```
void f(int x)
{
 ... ... ...;/*Whatever is required*/
}
```